# Unintended basket sharing between applications

Tags: intershop

I have a problem with unintended data sharing between different applications under same channel.
The problem is that is user adds items to a basket in one application, then that same basket can be viewed in different application that is not intended for the type of items that are in basket.
Below is the layout of applications under a single channel:

[image: Application layout in backoffice]

My question is whether is it possible to enforce different sessions for different application types (perhaps with a configuration setting) or whether there is some other built-in way of preventing data sharing between applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. This is not possible to be achieved. By design, the Site is the session container of Intershop Commerce Suite. Within the Site different applications share the same storefront session.

Comment: Certain aspects can be managed application specific (e.g. CMS) but the user repository will always be on channel/site level. You could try to use persistent baskets instead of session baskets but the problem that a logged in user is associated with a basket still remains.